# convert list of tuples into single column of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of tuple like this :

```
list_t = [(1,2),(1,7),(1,8),(2,6),(5,8)]
```

I want to make data frame out this but just one column:

[image]

Currently using this

```
df_com = pd.DataFrame(list_t,columns=["so","des"])
```

but then I have to join them again so operation cost is increased.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert list of tuples to `Series`:

```
s = pd.Series(list_t)
print (s)
0    (1, 2)
1    (1, 7)
2    (1, 8)
3    (2, 6)
4    (5, 8)
dtype: object
```

For DataFrame add [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = pd.Series(list_t).to_frame('new')
print (df)
      new
0  (1, 2)
1  (1, 7)
2  (1, 8)
3  (2, 6)
4  (5, 8)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not converting each to str:

```
import pandas as pd
list_t = [(1,2),(1,7),(1,8),(2,6),(5,8)]
list_t = [str(item) for item in list_t]
df_com = pd.DataFrame(list_t,columns=["tuples"])
print(df_com)
```

Output:

```
   tuples
0  (1, 2)
1  (1, 7)
2  (1, 8)
3  (2, 6)
4  (5, 8)
```

Just a note that this is faster from above

(although it is 'elegant'):

```
timeit("""import pandas as pd;list_t=[(1,2),(1,7),(1,8),(2,6),(5,8)];pd.Series(list_t).to_frame('new');""",number=1000)
     0.25547240000014426
timeit("""import pandas as pd;list_t=[(1,2),(1,7),(1,8),(2,6),(5,8)];pd.DataFrame({'tuple': list_t});""",number=1000)
     0.19921229999999923
```

Current answer:

```
timeit("""import pandas as pd;list_t=[(1,2),(1,7),(1,8),(2,6),(5,8)];list_t = [str(item) for item in list_t];pd.DataFrame(list_t,columns=["tuples"]);""",number=1000)
0.144553399999495
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass a `dict` to the `DataFrame` constructor.

```
pd.DataFrame({'tuple': list_t})

    tuple
0  (1, 2)
1  (1, 7)
2  (1, 8)
3  (2, 6)
4  (5, 8)
```